# What is the simple way to synchronize to folder using .Net?

Tags: c#, .net

What is the simple way to synchronize files between source and target directories in .Net without using other libraries?

Comment: Please add a comment when downvoting.

Comment: There is no simple way except to write a lot of code.

Comment: Compare folders (sub-folders?), if difference is found (first occurrence) - decide what to do, do that, start again until no differences found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [Microsoft Sync Framework.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh882034(v=sql.110).aspx)

Here is an example from MSDN for [synchronizing files](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb902813(v=sql.110).aspx) using the above.

Answer (score 0):

Robomojo - A .Net shell for RoboCopy.

http://robomojo.codeplex.com/

A .Net shell for RoboCopy. Copy whole directory structures with ease. Ideal for backups and deployments. Store your RoboCopy.exe commands for easy (and repeatable) use. WPF front-end, DI data access.

Comment: I have the requirement ofusing only .Net framework thanks!